# At what age does bed-sharing become detrimental to a child?

Tags: age-appropriate, research, bed-sharing

I'm making an assumption that there has to be an age at which bed-sharing no longer provides a benefit to either party and in fact is harmful to at least one of them. Are there any studies that prove this point? If so, is it possible these studies are simply biased by cultural norms and don't show actual harm to parent or child?

Hopefully the study would answer these questions:

1. When should parents stop sleeping in the same bed as their child?
2. What kind of issues can this cause for both the child and the parent
   if the bed-sharing continues beyond what is recommended?
3. Does the answer vary depending on whether we are talking about a single parent vs. a
   couple?

Comment: Cultural norms are important to take into consideration, as you and your children don't exist outside of them; that doesn't mean you need to be a slave to them, though. It just means it's something to think about. The literature on co-sleeping is easily accessible. Googling "effects of long term co-sleeping on parents and children" gave me a first page with some good and some mediocre information.

Comment: For 3) If a parent doesn't want the child in bed with them, it's "harmful", at least to the sleep of that parent. So, having 2 parents increases the chances that one of them doesn't want the child to cosleep anymore. This happened sooner for me than it did my wife. Once my son started moving more/getting bigger, I couldn't sleep comfortably.

Comment: Latent - please have a look at http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/197/316 and the other Related questions from the sidebar to the right

Comment: Co-sleeping is pretty harmful to sleep hygiene and that detriment starts early - about six months old. There's a bunch of risk associated with co-sleeping so it's hard to say when co-sleeping is not detrimental to the child.

Comment: It's hard for me to see this having a concrete answer, despite the effort the asker made in framing it.  Beofett's answer to the linked question is probably the closest you can come, and the data in it is very mixed itself.

Comment: @joe: The fact that there is no definitive answer is itself an answer - it means that there's no inherent benefit or harm, and parents can follow their personal or cultural leanings with a clear conscience.

Comment: @Marc Sorry, I don't think that sentence makes any sense.  There may be benefits and/or harms - probably are both - but they're too hard to quantify to make this question answerable.  Certainly it's not answerable as "At what age does it become detrimental", given most of the harms quoted occur at *young* ages (ie, children dying from smothering).

Comment: Clearly, there aren't huge benefits or huge harms, and that's the answer to the question. "It doesn't seem to matter, at least not enough to be obvious in the studies done" is an answer. Learn to live with ambiguity. Science is full of it.

Comment: What detriment are you concerned about? Smothering? Immediately a concern at birth. Attachment/Detachment issues? It's a problem when the child consistently refuses to sleep in his own bed. (Your society may disagree with this, but if you aren't sleeping in your parent's bed, maybe your kid shouldn't, either.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is a definitive answer for this question.  The behavioral and development specialists at the children's hospital where my sons PCP is all agree that co-sleeping is bad and should only be allowed as an exception to comfort a child on stormy nights or after other upsetting events.  Their arguments are that it prevents children from developing confidence and independence that becomes crucial in early education, and the development of trust that even though they can't see mommy/daddy they are still there.

Still other professionals make the exact opposite arguments that the more nurturing co-sleeping reduces separation based stress which in turn promotes stronger development of emotional stability and key skills.

I found a study from 2007 that states there is some accuracy to both sides.  I would read a few articles from both sides then play it by ear with consideration of your child's specific behaviors.

[LiveStrong - good effects](http://www.livestrong.com/article/245233-long-term-effects-of-sleeping-with-children/)
[PsychologyToday - bad effects](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/savvy-parenting/201403/the-impact-chronic-co-sleeping-older-child)
[University of California - Full Study](https://webfiles.uci.edu/lyar/familylab/goldberg/Dr._Goldberg_files/Goldberg%20%26%20Keller%20Findings%20and%20Future.pdf)